# Odoo10 - Use JQuery selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, odoo

I am using Odoo 10.

I need to use JQuery selectors instead *$el.find* to navigate the DOM, but I'm having some difficulties. Is there a specific Widget I should extend to do that?

For now I achieved this task only setting a timeout, but I would prefer to not do that.

My code:

```
openerp.grid = function(instance, local) {

local.GridWidget = instance.web.form.FormWidget.extend({
    start: function () {
        this._super.apply(this, arguments)
        var self = this

        var container = document.createElement('div')
        container.className = 'grid_container'
        this.$el.append(container)

        self.draw_grid()
    },
    draw_grid: function() {

        var grid;
        var columns = [
            {id: 'title', name: 'Title', field: 'title'},
            {id: 'attr', name: 'Attribute', field: 'attr'},
        ]
        var options = {
            enableCellNavigation: true,
            enableColumnReorder: false,
        };
        var data = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
        data[i] = {
            title: "Task " + i,
            attr: "Attr " + i,
          };
        }

        setTimeout(function() {
            grid = new Slick.Grid('.grid_container', data, columns, options);
        }, 50)
    }

})
instance.web.form.custom_widgets.add('GridWidget','instance.grid.GridWidget')
```

}

Comment: control the API of `instance.web.form.FormWidget`, maybe there is a method / option like _onLoaded_, _onRender_, or similar. Hope it helps!

Comment: I already tried that. There is a *renderElement* function but it is not even triggered where I need it.

Comment: Which version of Odoo are you working on ?

Comment: I am using the 10th version.

Comment: Where exactly do you set the jquery selector and it does not work ?

Comment: I'm using an external plugin. So I don't know every line where it does not work yet.

For now I saw that it works on some calls and it does not in other ones.
I'm trying then to find out all these calls to figure the problem out, but I'm still not succeeding.